# Pulling combined results from 'hierarchical' data in a table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm not so good in SQL, it's Monday, we had a party last night I can't think straight, I need your help guys.

If I have data in a sql table. something like that:

```
ModelName    Color   Garageld

BMW          Black   NULL
Mercedes     Red     NULL
Audi         Yellow  NULL
BMW          Green   1
Mercedes     Blue    1
```

And now using LINQtoEntities I need to get all the records for a garage with id == 1 where it should combine records - If there is a color defined for the garage and a car - get it, if there is none, take whatever color is for NULL

So the result set for the garageId == 1 should be:

```
Audi         Yellow  
BMW          Green   
Mercedes     Blue
```

Comment: Based on your example, why is Audi included in the list (GarageID is null)

Comment: @Sparky because he has to return it to whoever gave him the keys at the party

Comment: let's put it that way: there is default car models and colors for all garages, and specifically defined colors for garages. I need to get entire list - all the colors for garage #1 and whatever is missing, but defined in defaults

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this by using an outer join from default (null) garage entries to the garage 1 entries.  Use COALESCE(), which is a standard SQL function that returns its first non-null argument.

```
SELECT dflt.ModelName, COALESCE(g.Color, dflt.Color) AS Color
FROM mytable AS dflt
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable AS g
  ON dflt.ModelName = g.ModelName AND g.GarageId = 1
WHERE dflt.GarageId IS NULL
```

When this is no garage 1 entry found for a given model, the outer join makes *all* columns null for `g.*` so COALESCE() will skip g.Color and use dflt.Color instead.

Comment: Thanks.. but what about LINQ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about using LINQ.